# NIM string to seq[string] (split by words)

Tags: nim-lang

I have a `string` that I need to convert to `seq[string]`

simple example given below:

```
let string1 = "this is a string"
var cmd: seq[string]
```

How do I get the `string1` to be converted or cast into my `seq[string]` format e.g.

```
@["this", "is", "a", "string"]
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Yeah you want to split your string into multiple strings, but what is your exact endgoal? Do you want a sequence of strings that are all 1 character of `string1`? Do you want each string in the sequence to be a word, so a sequence of 4 strings ("This", "is", "a" and "string")? Do you want the same string 5000 times?
What you've written indicates that you want to use of the split proc (or the identically named iterator) of `std/strutils`.  You can find docs on that lib with all other nim std libs here: https://nim-lang.org/docs/lib.html

Comment: I would like to split into a sequence of 4 strings.

Comment: So basically, if there is a space between them, you want it to count as a new string. Definitely take a look at `split` in the `strutils` nim standard library. Look at what it does and the examples for it, it's pretty much exactly what you want. Once you've figured that out you can answer your own question for the next person that might stumble over your question ;-)

Comment: [With this](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#split%2Cstring%2Cstring%2Cint) or [this](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#splitWhitespace,string,int)

Answer (score 2):

```
import strutils

var string1 = "this is a string"
echo string1.split(' ')
```

this display

```
@["this", "is", "a", "string"]
```